# Searchbar for users in laravel blade template

Tags: laravel

I'm making a searchbar for my website, I wanna filter users for username.
My function in controller look like this:

```
  function search_users(Request $request) {
        if ($request->search) {
            $searchUsers = User::where('username', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->search. '%')->get();
            $data = [
                "users" => $searchUsers
            ];
            //return response()->json($searchUsers);
          return view('dashboard.home', $data);
        }else {
            return response()->json("no_results");
          //  return view('dashboard.home');
        }
    }
```

```
    <form action="{{route('search')}}" method="get">
                <input type="search" name="username" id="" placeholder="Cerca" class="searchbar">
                <button type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
```

If I try to make a search I receive no_results response also if I have this username stored into db, probably I wrong to set something inside my blade file

Comment: you need to change name in your form or used set name in your controller file. like username

Answer (score 1):

Inside your form you named the input as

```
name="username"
```

inside your controller you have to use the same name

```
if ($request->username)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$request->search` by `$request->username`, because the name of your input is `username` and you used the type of the input

```
 function search_users(Request $request) {
    if (isset($request->username)) {
        $users = User::where('username', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->username.'%')->get();

    }else{
       $users = null;
    }
  return view('dashboard.home', $users);
}
```